# Convert video into format which is most likely playable on a windows system

Tags: windows, linux, video, video-encoding

I have some `flv` and `mp4` videos, which I need to convert to a format which is playable on an a Windows Vista system (for a presentation). The problem is, that I cannot test the videos on the system on the presentation. I guess that no additional codes are installed on the windows system. I am not sure if vlc is installed.

So the problem is to convert the videos to an format which is most likely causes no problems on an partially unknown windows system. What would you suggest?

Please provide the exact parameters for `ffmpeg` or `mencoder` or `avidemux` (whatever you want).

**Edit** Just realized that I also need to specify an audio codec (for example in `avidemux`), so which one should I use?

Comment: If you can run programs on the target computer (i.e. there's no group policy or otherwise that will block executables), I would recommend using [a portable copy of VLC](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable) running off a flash drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For compatibility, MPEG-1 is the best choice.  An MPEG-1 codec has been included standard on Windows since at least XP SP2.

Comment: In avidemux there are two MPEG-1 options, "mpeg2enc" and "avcodec", which one to use?

Comment: I thought DVD:s used MPEG-2?

Comment: Yup, DVDs don't use MPEG-1, only Video CDs do.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has released [FAQ on codecs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Codecs-frequently-asked-questions).

> There are hundreds of audio and video codecs in use today. Some have been created by Microsoft, but the vast majority of codecs have been created by other companies, organizations, or individuals. By default, the Windows operating system and the Player include a number of the **most popular codecs**, such as **Windows Media Audio, Windows Media Video, and MP3**.

Go figure.

As Kyle already said, MPEG-1 is the only option that's left for you. Note though that it has been developed in 1988 and the quality you'll get is *ridiculously* bad. As for audio, I'd use MP3 if Microsoft says it's supported – otherwise go for MP2.

For FFmpeg, that'd be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v mpeg1video -q:v 3 -c:a libmp3lame out.avi
```

Replace the value in `-q:v 3` in order to get different quality output. The higher this number, the worse the quality. Replace `libmp3lame` with `mp2` for MP2 audio instead of MP3.

Comment: Thanks. The `mpeg1video` option you used is this the same as MPEG-1 with `mpeg2enc` or with `avcodec` in `avidemux` or is is again something different?

Comment: I get the message "unrecognized option c:v"

Comment: What version of FFmpeg are you running? (What OS are you on, even?) — As for `mpeg2enc`, it's a separate program. `avcodec` refers to `libavcodec` and it's the codec library used in FFmpeg, so these are the same if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: On ubuntu natty: ffmpeg version 4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2+codecs1~natty3

Comment: Jeez, version 0.6! That's more than a year old! Quick, [install the latest one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095), which definitely supports the syntax. I always recommend that tutorial, it should be easy to follow.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you download [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to handle the conversion into MP4 format, which is about as universal as these things get, and make sure the system that needs to play it has [vlc](http://www.videolan.org/) installed.

The former program has a very user-friendly GUI to convert any video format into almost any other; the latter runs on most platforms I'm aware of and can play any video format I've managed to throw at it.

Comment: Windows needs codecs for MP4, I think

Comment: Windows needs codecs for almost anything except Windows Media files and MP3, see my answer and the link to Microsoft's own FAQ.