# ffmpeg / avconv to ensure compatibilty with Windows DirectShow

Tags: video, ffmpeg, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a video file:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from ron_1080p.mp4':

 Metadata:     
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:09:07.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7482 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 7346 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
```

I need to send this to someone and be certain that they can embed it as-is into a Powerpoint presentation, which means using DirectShow supported codecs only.

What ffmpeg/avconv command can I use to ensure it will be compatible, and retain as much quality as possible?

Comment: which target version of Windows?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/435941/which-codecs-are-most-suitable-for-playback-with-windows-media-player-on-windows or http://superuser.com/questions/418945/convert-video-into-format-which-is-most-likely-playable-on-a-windows-system